# Changing two letters to one in translation

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a text to runes converter, fairly simple, but I cant make it change two letters into one: th = þ, ae = æ, oe = ø.
I'm a complete new beginner, and can't see what's wrong.

I know the last replacements looks weird, but space and comma must actually be : in runes, and they work fine. It's the th, ae and oe stuff that fails to execute.

It all works fine, except to letters to one replacement.
[www.vikingr.site](http://www.vikingr.site) –> Fuþark

```js
function generateCursiveText() {
  const cursiveDict = {"a":"ᚨ","b":"ᛒ","c":"ᚲ","d":"ᛞ","e":"ᛖ","f":"ᚠ","g":"ᚷ","h":"ᚺ","i":"ᛁ","j":"ᛃ","k":"ᚴ","l":"ᛚ",    "m":"ᛗ","n":"ᚾ","o":"ᛟ","p":"ᛈ","q":"ᛩ","r":"ᚱ","s":"ᛋ","þ":"ᚦ","t":"ᛏ","u":"ᚢ","v":"ᚡ","w":"ᚹ",    "x":"ᛪ","y":"ᚤ","z":"ᛉ","æ":"ᛇ","ä":"ᛇ","ø":"ᛟ","ö":"ᛟ","å":"ᚨ"," ":":",",":":"};
  const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input").value.toLowerCase().trim();
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < textInput.length; i++) {
    if (cursiveDict[textInput[i]]) {
      output += cursiveDict[textInput[i]];
    } else {
      output += textInput[i];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  //var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copy-it');
}

function replaceSpelling(input) {
  input = input.replace(/th/g, "þ");
  input = input.replace(/ae/g, "æ");
  input = input.replace(/oe/g, "ø");
  var lastChar = input[input.length - 1];
  return input;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-input"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="generateCursiveText()">convert</button>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you calling the `replaceSpelling()` function anywhere? I can see that its defined but can't see it being called anywhere. Also if you can, please try and make a [mre], all the clipboard-related code, and reading the input from the HTML doesn't seem like it's necessary to reproduce the issue in your question.

Comment: I removed a few `.` from your code and commented the clipboard one out to make a [mcve]

Comment: I would consider `ᛅ`  or `ᚫ` for æ,  `ᚯ` for ø and `ᚬ` for å

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to replace them first, and then replace every character with translated one or itself if translation is missing
edit: case insensitive - `i` flag and `.toLowerCase()`
edit: it's better to unify those to a single regex to avoid double replacement

```js
const cursiveDict = {
    "th":"þ" , "ae":"æ" , "oe":"ø",
    "a":"ᚨ","b":"ᛒ","c":"ᚲ","d":"ᛞ","e":"ᛖ","f":"ᚠ","g":"ᚷ","h":"ᚺ","i":"ᛁ","j":"ᛃ","k":"ᚴ","l":"ᛚ",    "m":"ᛗ","n":"ᚾ","o":"ᛟ","p":"ᛈ","q":"ᛩ","r":"ᚱ","s":"ᛋ","þ":"ᚦ","t":"ᛏ","u":"ᚢ","v":"ᚡ","w":"ᚹ",    "x":"ᛪ","y":"ᚤ","z":"ᛉ","æ":"ᛇ","ä":"ᛇ","ø":"ᛟ","ö":"ᛟ","å":"ᚨ"," ":":",",":":"
  };
function update() {
  let text = taIn.value;
  text = text.replace(/th|ae|oe|./g,
      s => cursiveDict[s.toLowerCase()] ?? s
  );
  taOut.value = text;
}
update()
```

```html
<textarea id="taIn" cols=30 rows=20 oninput="update()">
I'm implementing a text to runes converter, fairly simple, but I cant make it change two letters into one: th = þ, ae = æ, oe = ø. I'm a complete new beginner, and can't see what's wrong.
</textarea>
<textarea id="taOut" cols=30 rows=20></textarea>
```

Comment: @mplungjan the inner textarea was initial value lol

Comment: I did change it but there were some desyncs because of simultaneous editing

Comment: But it doesn't work. There is no æ or ø in the output.

Comment: @PalleDue that's because `cursiveDict = {..., "ø":"ᛟ", ...}` (but why) :thinking:

Comment: Thank you so so much! It works like a dream! :-)